# functionality testing of controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have product controller in that i have method say homepage and _homepage.html.erb file in views. How to test this method to get assert should get response success. I created productcontrllertest.rb in test/functional and wrote below code

```
require 'test_helper'
class ProductControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

 test "should get homepage" do
    get :homepage
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

and i have routes.rb file with get "product/homepage"

when i run test with command bundle exec rake test:functionals i am getting error.

```
Error is that NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Hello! If you are new at RoR and testing checkout this great tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.  Author is telling a lot about different testing tools. I'm using RSpec, so I don't work with asserts at all.

Comment: One more question, have you opened this page in browser ? Maybe you REALLY have NoMethodError in your controller ?

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: def homepage
    @brands=Brand.where("featured=?",1)
end

Comment: It looks like you're using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or some other user authentication mechanism (perhaps you rolled your own).  You probably have to login before you access that page.

Comment: I am not using devise.

Comment: in routes.rb  match "homepage/1" => 'product_details#homepage'

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'test_helper'
class ProductControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

 test "should get homepage" do
    get 'homepage/1'
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Comment: in routes.rb file i wrote code: match "homepage/1" => 'product#homepage' so if i execute above suggested code i am getting error  ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"product", :action=>"homepage/1"}

Comment: what is the result or `rake routes`?